# Is SetAsFirstSibling or SetAsLastSibling better to use in Unity?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, gameobject

This wouldn't be hard to test but I'm curious if anyone's already tested this: is there a difference in performance for setting a newly instantiated gameobject as the first vs. last sibling in a hierarchy? For example, I could order a list of gameobjects in descending order and set each gameobject as the last sibling or order it in ascending order and set each as the first to get my desired order.

I'm asking because it reminded me of the performance gain of inserting at the head of a linked list vs. at the end in order to avoid traversal of the list.

Comment: Sounds like a great exercise for ILSpy. https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/09/02/a-practical-tutorial-to-hack-and-protect-unity-games/

Comment: I think it'd be easier to just time the difference but interesting article, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, just thought it'd be a good read.

Comment: Based on what I know, if you instantiate an object *and then* change its parent, that requires Unity to recompute the transform hierarchy (which are fixed sized arrays) twice. If you instantiate while indicating a parent, that will recompute once. SetAsLastChild probably costs nothing (beyond the aforementioned and some function overhead). SetAsFirstChild would require a recompute of that object's child list (but less than adding a new child).

Comment: I wish there was a way to instantiate while indicating the parent AND specifying the index (ala SetSiblingIndex). I'm trying to reuse prefabs - via SetActive(bool) - rather than destroying them and re-instantiating.  It's like a table view with rows, but I have to inserts dividers between certain rows - which vary depending on the page you're viewing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Children are automatically added as last siblings upon instantiation so setting any as first siblings would be more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care for objects precendence, why set child order at all?
Internally, the hierarchy is actually stored on the C++ side of the engine, so doing micro-optimisations at this level are just wasting time - the fact you are making a P/Invoke call to the unmanaged side is probably more expensive than the difference between first and last its quite likely that its more similar to an ordinary array, than to a list, on the other side.

Comment: Oh, you're saying instantiate all the gameobjects without order and then assign their variables in order? They will need differing sizes based on their content but perhaps I only need one layout call to resize them. That sounds like a great idea I'll try it out. Also what do you mean the unmanaged side?

Comment: It turns out the children are automatically created as last siblings so that solves that.