# Setting a prefab as child of another game object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject, prefab

```
 public GameObject aiArrow;
 aiArrow.transform.parent = this.gameObject.transform;
```

When I try to set up a prefab as a child of another object the following error occurs.

> Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is
> disabled to prevent data corruption

How to Set up this "aiArrow" Prefab as a child of another game object.

Comment: when is your prefab gameObject instantiated?

Comment: You probably want to set the parent of an **instantiated** object in your scene .... not of the prefab **asset** ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this action right in the `Instantiate()` function call.

```
public Transform parentObject;
public GameObject prefab;

public void CreateObject()
{
   Instantiate(prefab, parentObject);
}
```

The method `Instantiate` has several overloads, where you can specify a parent object. This was the simplest example. Important! The example above does NOT modify position or rotation. It only acts as you would drag&drop a gameobject in the `Hierarchy` below another one. See [Instatiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) for the overload you need.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to instantiate under a parent, but insert it in between some existing child prefabs (not just at the end). Purpose is during a refresh/reload to reuse some of the child prefabs via SetActive(bool) rather than destroying them and re-instantiating everything.

Comment: Oh, found this...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106736/unity-add-child-to-children-but-at-top

Comment: And this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52651495/is-setasfirstsibling-or-setaslastsibling-better-to-use-in-unity